# how to work treeview nodes contains in asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

these codes are not working. how to add only one value. i can not use .Nodes.Contains method.For example : my customer:
yusuf1, yusuf2,yusuf1, yusuf4; i see treeview yusuf1, yusuf2,yusuf1, yusuf4;. But i want to see yusuf1, yusuf2, yusuf4

```
   protected void FillTreeViewCustomers()
        {
            MyClass mytest = new MyClass ();
            IEnumerable<Quotation> mytestList = mytest .GetAll();
            foreach MyClass item in mytestList )
            {
                            
                TreeNode newnode = new TreeNode() { Text = item.Customer, Value = item.Customer };
                if (!treeViewCustomer.Nodes.Contains(newnode))
                {
                    treeViewCustomer.Nodes.Add(newnode);
                }
               

            }
        }
```

Comment: This code is incomplete and/or contains errors. Where does quotationList come from?

Comment: did your treeViewCustomer have nodes collection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `treeViewCustomer.Nodes.Contains(newnode)` is that this method checks for reference equality only. You cannot use it to determine whether an equivalent but different node is in the collection.

There are a few options available to you however, such as doing a `foreach` loop to look for matching nodes, or by assigning a unique key to the treenode when you add it, and using the `.ContainsKey` method.  I think TreeNodeCollection uses `Name` as the Key.

So, in your example - something like this should do it

```
if (!treeViewCustomer.Nodes.ContainsKey(item.Customer)
{
   treeViewCustomer.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode { 
     Name=item.Customer, 
     Text=item.Customer, 
     Value=item.Customer 
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Programmerist: The problem is how TreeNode.Contains  compares the nodes while searching the  TreeNodeCollection. I had this problem as well, and decided to do a foreach on the collection to compare fields manually.

Obs: remember that there two differente but similar types of tree nodes

```
    System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a copy of your code or a freehand expression?

In your example you're creating a collection of items called "mytestList" but then use "quotationList" in your foreach loop.

Also, you code is missing:

```
treeViewCustomer.DataBind();
```

Are you doing this elsewhere?

Comment: DataBind() is only useful when a DataSource is used.

Answer (score 0):

The line `if (!treeViewCustomer.Nodes.Contains(newnode))` will always be true because the object that it's checking the collection for has just been created.

If you want to avoid adding an equivalent node, you need to alter the way that you're checking the collection.